# Mobile App Security w/HTTPS POST

Tags: jquery, security, mobile, ssl, asp.net-web-api

I am in the final stages of developing a mobile app, but am curious about one aspect with it. Under normal circumstances, things such as login pages and whatnot on a standard website should always be secured with SSL, however I'm not 100% certain how that correlates to an HTML5-based mobile app. If I have an area in the app where data that I wish to be secured (and ultimately encrypted in the database) is being sent via HTTP POST, if the URL I am posting to is protected via SSL, is it a secure transmission? I'm assuming so, but am not finding a lot of detail in either direction so I am curious if this works as expected. The backend is guaranteed using an SSL certificate from a trusted authority, so if I post to that is the payload encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

*Answering old question just for completeness.*

Well, everything depends on the platform, as always. As long as the platform you're using conforms to the standards, then yes, SSL should be secure, as long as the platform uses proper implementation of SSL and uses it correctly. Of course, the platform could be prone to mischief, and with a sinister chuckle could secretly change your `https://` url to `http://`, while still pretending to use SSL, but you can probably say how unlikely that would be.

You can always check what happens on the server side, and be sure.